# List directories python OSX

Tags: python, macos, path, directory

I am having an issue with trying to list all of the files/folders within a directory with Python 2.6, on Mac OS X.

To simplify the problem, I am attempting to simply list all the files on my desktop (which is not empty).  I understand this can be done like this:

```
currentFileList = os.listdir("~/Desktop")
```

But I am getting the error:

```
currentFileList = os.listdir("~/Desktop")
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/Desktop'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try giving full path.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't figure that out before - thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should pass absolute pass to `os.listdir` function. You can use `os.expanduser` function to expand `~`:

```
os.listdir(os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop'))
```

By the way. Be careful: `~foobar` will replace the path with home folder for user `foobar` (e.g. `/home/foobar`)

Comment: `os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop')` is neater, and only uses one type of quote!

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you. Improved my answer with your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You need the full path not relative

```
os.listdir('/Users/YOURUSERNAME/Desktop')
```